# Avoid a for loop in raster::extract(rst,shp)

Tags: r, performance, raster, r-sf

I am working on R to extract the mean and maximum value of a raster within a 3 meter buffer of some buildings.

For this, I have created a for loop that iterates iterates through each building to extract this two values. My current code looks as follows:

```
for (b in c(1:nrow(buildings_shp))){
    
    building <- buildings_shp[b,]
    
    buffered <- st_buffer(building, 3)
    
    raster_cropped <- crop(raster, extent(buffered))

    mean <- extract(depths_cropped, buffered, fun = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
    max <- extract(depths_cropped, buffered, fun = max, na.rm = TRUE)
    
    buildings_shp[b,"mean"] <- mean
    buildings_shp[b,"max"] <- max
    
  }
```

This loop, however, takes a considerable amount of time (~17 minutes for 1500 buildings), and the step that seems to take most time is the two extract lines. I would like to know if there are ways to speed up this process by:

a) avoiding the use of a loop - the reason for this loop is that I fear that if I use st_buffer on the entire dataset, then when buildings are closer than 3 meters I would generate overlapping geometries, which may cause an error.

b) parallelizing the for loop (i have tried the raster clustering feature, but it did not speed up the process, probably because it did not parallelize the loop itself but the extract function)

c) using other function than raster::extract. I have seen some posts [recommending the velox package](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/286409/fastest-way-to-extract-a-raster-in-r-improve-the-time-of-my-reproducible-code), but it seems like this package has been removed from CRAN.

Some dummy data (copied from the referenced question above)

```
library(raster)
library(sf)

raster <- raster(ncol=1000, nrow=1000, xmn=2001476, xmx=11519096, ymn=9087279, ymx=17080719)
raster []=rtruncnorm(n=ncell(raster ),a=0, b=10, mean=5, sd=2)
crs(raster ) <- "+proj=utm +zone=51 ellps=WGS84"
    
x1 <- runif(100,2001476,11519096)
y1 <- runif(100, 9087279,17080719)

buildings_shp <- st_buffer(st_sfc(st_point(c(x1[1],y1[1]), dim="XY"),crs=32651),200000)
```

Comment: Cross-posted as https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/377872/115

Comment: Hi @PolyGeo - any advice on what to do? this cross-post was performed to reach to both communities - the coding / R users for programming and code efficiency, and the GIS users for spatial explicit issues. I can remove one of the questions or add the link to the question itself.

Comment: My main advice is not to cross-post in future - see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/215590 This cross-post has answers on both so l think you should leave them. If your earlier cross-posts have an answer on one but not the other site(s) then delete the one(s) without answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a loop.  Example data from `?raster::extract`

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=36, nrow=18, vals=1:(18*36))
cds1 <- rbind(c(-180,-20), c(-160,5), c(-60, 0), c(-160,-60), c(-180,-20))
cds2 <- rbind(c(80,0), c(100,60), c(120,0), c(120,-55), c(80,0))
buildings <- spPolygons(cds1, cds2)
```

Get the buffers and extract. As you want to compute two statistics, it is easier to not use a summarizing function in this case.

```
b <- buffer(buildings, width=3, dissolve=FALSE)
e <- extract(r, b)
```

And now compute the statistics

```
sapply(e, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
#[1] 379.4167 330.0741
sapply(e, max, na.rm=TRUE)
#[1] 507 498
```

This should be faster with `terra`

```
library(terra)
v <- vect(b)
x <- rast(r)
ee <- extract(x, v)
```

Comment: Thank you Robert - however, it seems like buffering the entire layer of buildings leads to overlapping geometries after the buffer. When I compared the results of using the loop and not using it, I saw that the results obtained were different. I have tested now again using your example (increasing the buffer to 150) and the results are now similar. Do you think this shouldnt be a problem?

Comment: Yes, they overlap, but that is not a problem